# counter-intuitive behavior of  isset()

Tags: php

I pass a variable $foo to a function.  This input variable might be an array or a string.  If it is an array, then I want to set:

```
$name = $foo['name']
```

And if it is a string, then I want to set:

```
$name = $foo
```

To accomplish this, I wrote the following code:

```
$name = isset($foo['name']) ? $foo['name'] : $foo
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.
The reason:  isset($foo['name']) returns TRUE when $foo is a string.

This behavior is suprising to me.  I had expected isset($foo['name']) to return FALSE because $foo['name'] is not set.  Can someone explain this seemingly counter-intuitive behavior?  Or suggest an alternative to isset() that returns FALSE on $foo['name'], when $foo is a string?

UPDATE:
See Christopher's suggestion below:

```
$name = ( is_array( $foo ) && isset( $foo['name'] ) ) ? $foo['name'] : $foo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't be at all surprising.

Why it evaluates true when $foo is a string: $foo['name'] is the same thing as asking for the zeroeth character of $foo when it's a string - because 'name' or 'camel' or 'cigar' or 'any other string' will be coerced into an integral value in that context.

array_key_exists() might also not be quite what you want, since it will return true *if the key is set* even if it has the null value.

in_array() would also be bad, as it will quietly search a string *or* an array without complaint.

Consider instead:

```
 $name = ( is_array( $foo ) && isset( $foo['name'] ) ) ? $foo['name'] : $foo;
```

Note that this does not take into account whatever you *do* plan to do if array and value for key 'name' is null, or if string and $foo is null, etc., which isn't a shortcoming on the part of the language but rather a piece of logic specific to your application.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly the clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The `set` in `isset` doesn't mean "a set of items," it means "was it assigned to," loosely. So, as you've said in your question, use `is_array` instead. If you realize that you can accomplish what you want without `isset`, *why not do so*?

See [the documentation for `isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).